# Filling the value in a column of a dataframe based on the value in a previous row and different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I would like to forward fill some data in the column `Drive` based on the values in `FPOS`.  If the value in `FPOS` in the row above is a 1, I would like the `Drive` value to increase by 1, otherwise I would like it to remain as the value above.  I feel like I am missing the simple method for doing this.  Thanks for any help.

```
Drive     FPOS
1           1
            0
            0
            0
            1
            0
            0
            ...
```

Comment: Please post sample of your output

Comment: and a reproducible and meaningful example of the input (more that one Drive)

Answer (score 0):

The exact logic and expected output is unclear, but from the description I imagine:

```
df['Drive2'] = df['Drive'].ffill().add(df['FPOS'].shift().eq(1).cumsum())
```

output (as new column Drive2 for clarity):

```
   Drive  FPOS  Drive2
0    1.0     1     1.0
1    NaN     0     2.0
2    NaN     0     2.0
3    NaN     0     2.0
4    NaN     1     2.0
5    NaN     0     3.0
6    NaN     0     3.0
```

Comment: @Joseph if this is not exactly what you want, please provide a better example with other Drive values